# Breaking a string into characters and compare with &&

Tags: c#, string

I have a string of mobile phone numbers suppose `string a = 098767555655`.Now as per my requirement i have to break it into individual characters and compare equality of  first two characters with `&&` and `.equals`..

I did like this but its not happening..

```
                    char[] dialednoArray = dialedno.ToCharArray();

                    if(dialednoArray[0] && dialednoArray[1].Equals("0"))
```

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to check if the string starts with two zeros?

```
bool startsWithTwoZeros = a.StartsWith("00");
```

another - less efficient - way using LINQ:

```
bool startsWithTwoZeros = a.Take(2).All(c => c == '0');
```

which would also fail if the string is `"0"`.

Comment: I like StartsWith - simple and fast

Answer (score 2):

I think you were trying to do this:

```
if(dialednoArray[0].Equals("0") && dialednoArray[1].Equals("0"))
```

Or you could take a substring:

```
if(a.Substring(0, 2) == "00")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dialednoArray[0] && dialednoArray[1].Equals("0"))
```

The problem here is that `dialednoArray[0]` is not a [boolean expresion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691320%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), thus the result of your && operator is undefined.